# How to real count repeated string in string in python?

Tags: python, string, count

I am sorry that I am not sure my question is correct or clear enough. However, I hope the example below can explain my question:

As what you see
`print("abbbbbbc".count("bbb")) #–output is 2`

But I want the result is 4, because bbbbbb has 6 characters and can breakdown as below:

bbb---

-bbb--

--bbb-

---bbb

I couldn't figure out which function I can use to solve this matter. What I did is count by for combinations, and it doesn't look right at all.

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own logic, like this:

```
a = "abbbbbbc"
b = "bbb"

count = 0
for i in range(len(a) - len(b)):
    if a[i:i+len(b)] == b:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

OR

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i:].startswith(b):
        count += 1
print(count)
```

OR

```
count = sum([1 if a[i:].startswith(b) else 0 for i in range(len(a))])
print(count)
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the answers from the suggestion above with overlapping count. However, you answers are also great!